# Smartdiagram error when compile

Tags: diagrams, compiling

I want to use the *smartdiagram* but by some reason a get a error:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \smartdiagram 
code #1#2->\StrCut {#1}{:}\diagramtype \option \IfNoValueTF {#... l.6 ...ram]
{Initiation,Planning,Execution,Closure} The control sequence at the end of 
the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled 
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). 
Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence. \smartdiagram
code ...\StrCut {#1}{:}\diagramtype \option \IfNoValueTF {#1}{... l.6 ...ram]
{Initiation,Planning,Execution,Closure} The control sequence at the end of 
the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled 
it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). 
Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Here are a the code I use.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Initiation,Planning,Execution,Closure}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no `diagram` option has been defined; you have to select, say `circular diagram`. You find the complete list of diagrams in the documentation. BTW: check that your distribution has the required packages (first section: Introduction and requirements).

Comment: change diagram to circular diagram, do not help.

Comment: Does your distribution has the necessary packages `xparse`, `etoolbox` and `xstring`, besides TikZ of course?

Comment: When I change the first code to: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Initiation,Planning,Execution,Closure}
    \end{center}
\end{document}` Do I still get a _error_

Comment: The packages I mentioned are already loaded by `smartdiagram`: I thought you missed `xstring` which would have been a possible cause of the error. Unfortunately I can compile without errors both codes you provide with both versions 0.2 and 0.3 (which I already sent to CTAN, so it's matter of days before having it available on TeXLive and MiKTeX).

Comment: The version 0.3 can be installed via package manager. You might try to update your distribution and see if the error persist: on Mac OSX I'm able to compile with success the example.

Comment: I *have the same problem* too.  My document worked well in february.  I left it without changing anything and returned to it on april 26, having the same problem.  I have checked the dependencies and all are fullfiled, except for TikZ for which I don't have a way to now what components of that package are installed.

I tested the example from the package documentation and the problem persists.


If I compile with a minimum example, only loading \usepackage{smartdiagram}, but not refering to it inside the document environment, the error shown says:  \usesmartdiagramlibrary{core.definitions}

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino

The new version of smartdiagram, works well.  Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: @djnavas: I've contacted Christian Schenk and now the problem should be fixed. Originally on http://miktex.org/packages/smartdiagram the number of files were 5 (I argued the libraries were missing) and now they are 9: indeed the libraries are 4. I think a new download from the manager should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify the additional packages. Smartdiagram will call them automatically.
Your MWE is correct and compiles (Kubuntu 12.10 but with a complete "vanilla Latex installation").
I had similar problems before, with the Texlive2012 PPA.
So if you are indeed working with xUbuntu, try a full "vanilla Latex".

Comment: I am working with OSX, unfortunately